# Graph API call returns GraphMethodException - why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Ok code-heads, riddle me this... I'm harvesting likes off posts, and I get some weird errors from the API. As an example, this post:

https://www.facebook.com/10151854248210966 (the post)

https://graph.facebook.com/likes?id=10151854248210966 (the graph call for likes)

returns a "GraphMethodException" - no idea why. However, The very next post:

https://www.facebook.com/10151780170490966 (the post)

https://graph.facebook.com/likes?id=10151780170490966 (the graph call for likes)

Spits out all the likes I can handle. I've noticed that some posts do this, and I simply can't figure it out. Any ideas and ways to fix it? If I pop the likes window, the likes are there, so why doesn't Graph API return them?

Comment: Not everything is public in facebook!

Comment: Sahil, everything that doesn't require a token IS public. My question was why one call returns data and the other, near identical call is returning the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. check this link with different user you cant access this page 
   beacause post with this id `10151854248210966` is private and not public..

if you want to access any not public object then you need to pass with access token

```
https://www.facebook.com/10151854248210966?access_token="{token}"
```

[Facebook Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)

and this post below is public so you can make request

```
https://www.facebook.com/10151780170490966
```

beacause is public

Comment: Thanks very much! Any idea how to tell if a post is public or private other than the error?